# Sending Push Notification from OS X to iOS doesn't work anymore. OS X network service changed?

Tags: macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, osx-yosemite

I am developing on two apps, a OS X app and an iOS app. In some conditions the OS X app should emit a signal to the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). The APNS than sends a Push Notification to the iOS app. This process works fine using OS X 10.8(.5), 10.9(.5) and OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

Using OS X 10.10.3 or 10.10.5 the Push Notification sent by the OS X app doesn't receive the iOS app. Seems the communication between OS X and the APNS is broken.

Reading the OS X 10.10.4 release notes, I found out that Apple improves the networking reliability for 10.10.4.
Could it be that something was broken inside OS X 10.10.3? Maybe they did some changes for OSX 10.10.5 again?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

<s>Maybe you must set a network security exception in the App that sends the APN. Because Apple deny any outgoing connection that is not secure.</s> Which program do you use to send the APN? Have you written the Server yourself? If yes, can you edit your question with the part of the source code which sends the APN, so I can test it myself?
If no, which Framework/Sample code do you use? PushMeBaby?

Edit: Apple has a new provider API that uses HTTP2. HTTP2 is faster and gives a Feedback back to the Server(Instant Feedback), the Payload size is now 4kb and there is a new certificate handling.